# Send bulk Mail Notifications

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient

I want to send above 500 to 2500 mails at a time using SMTP currently it is working for me but it is taking too much for all mails have to delivered so please suggest me the best method to send bulk mails with very less possible time, I used the below code.

```
string readMail = null;
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtpClient = null;
smtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtpClient.Port = 587;
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@example.net", "password");
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(cleint_Responce);
object userState = m;
try
{
     smtpClient.SendAsync(m,userState); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gmail isn’t designed for sending bulk email. If you are planning to send an email message to a large group of friends using Gmail, do read the following rules to avoid temporary lockdown of your Gmail:

Rule 1: You can send emails to a maximum of 500 recipients per day through the Gmail website. Try exceeding the limit and your Gmail account may get temporarily disabled with the error – “Gmail Lockdown in Section 4.”

It is important to note that this limit is around recipients and not messages. Thus you can send 10 emails to 50 people each or 1 email can be addressed to a maximum of 500 people.

Rule 2: If you access Gmail via POP or IMAP clients, like Microsoft Outlook or Apple Mail, you can send an email message to a maximum of 100 people at a time. If you exceed the limit, your account may be disabled for a day with the error – “550 5.4.5 Daily sending quota exceeded.”

Rule 3: Always double check email addresses of recipients before hitting the Send button in Gmail. That’s because your account may get disabled if the email message contains a large number of non-existent or broken addresses (<25 ?) that bounce back on failed delivery.

Rule 4: You can associate multiple email addresses with your Gmail account and send emails on behalf of any other address. However, when sending mail from a different address, the original account’s message limits are applied.

Rule 5: If you are sending emails through Google Script, like in the case of Gmail Mail Merge, the daily sending limit is 100 recipients per day for free Gmail accounts. You can use the MailApp.GetRemainingDailyQuota method to know your existing quota else the script will throw an exception saying – “Service invoked too many times.”

If you wish to send more email messages through Google Scripts, you’ll have to upgrade to Google Apps. Even then, your sending limits will be only be increased after a few billing cycles or if you have opted for 5 or more users.

There are some paid service will help you better on this like [Sendblaster](http://www.sendblaster.com/)